# Prove that this number is an integer

Tags: permutations, integers

Prove that the number
$${4155 \cdot4156 \cdot\ldots \cdot4251 \over 2 \cdot3 \cdot\ldots \cdot 97}$$
is an integer.

How might I prove this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the binomial coefficient $\binom {4251}{97}$

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!